# An incorrect result when converting date-time into unix timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this date-time in UTC/GMT

'2016-02-10T15:10:00.000Z'

I want to convert it into unix timestamp. Here it is:

```
from datetime import timezone, datetime
# ....

dt1 = '2016-02-10T15:10:00.000Z'
dt2 = dt1.replace('T', ' ').replace('.000Z', '')
unix_ts1 = datetime.fromisoformat(dt2).timestamp()

===>

1455124200.0
```

However, that's incorrect, and the correct result should've been `1455117000000` (ms) or `1455117000` (sec)

What's the matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: @lynmx no!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It's being parsed in your local timezone, not UTC, so it's off by 2 hours.

Comment: @Barmar how to make it parse it in UTC/GMT?

Comment: Don't remove the `Z` timezone code?

Comment: @Barmar try it youself to be able to see an issue

Comment: I think lots of the answers to the linked question show how to do it.

Comment: Looks like you need to use `strptime()` instead of `fromisoformat()`